# How to store the data in session after clicking on save button in php and submit the data after clicking on submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

Hi how to save the data in session when we click on save button and need to submit the data in database when i click on submit button.Here is my form.

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="personal.php" id="myform">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" value=""  />
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" value=""  />
<button class = "medium" style="background-color: #2daebf;">Save</button>
```

Personal.php

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(first_name,last_name)values("$firstname","$lastname")");
```

How can i store these data into sessions and redirect to indexs.php and once i click on submit button total data needs to be inserted into database.

```
indexs.php

<form method="post" action="personals.php" id="myform">
<label>Address</label>
<input type="text" name="address" value=""  />
<label>Pincode</label>
<input type="text" name="pin" value=""  />
<button class = "medium" type="submit" style="background-color: #2daebf;">Save</button>
```

Personals.php

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$address = $_POST['address'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(address,pin)values("$address","$pin")");
```

Comment: which data do you want to store in SESSION?

Comment: Your question is so much confusing . You have written the same code two times. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: the data which i entered in index.php that data i need to store in sessions and need to redirect to indexs.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Form Data as a Session Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791414/storing-form-data-as-a-session-variable)

Comment: @Drudge one form is for personal info section and another is for address section after filling the personalinfo section i need to store that data in session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can save whole post data in php sessions.

```
<?php
session_start();

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
$address = $_POST['address'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(address,pin)values("$address","$pin")");

//Session Work
$_SESSION['form_data'] = $_POST;
header ('location' : 'indexs.php');
}
```

Comment: can you edit in my code it should be saved in sessions and need to store the data in database

Comment: @user5891511, I have edited my answer. Use this code in your personal.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a table and store your data in table. And then create session by retrieving data from table. This is the best way to use session i think.