# sliding through html pages next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating multi page form on 4 different pages. I want to include a next and previous button to be able to navigate through the form. I have searched online but what i find is usually navigating `<div>`s on a page. How do I change this to do my bidding? Thank you in advance.

this is the code for the previous button i found online. `.registration-form` is the name of a form. I want to change this to navigate through my `html` pages.

```
$('.registration-form .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).prev().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Forms on the different pages have names `part1`, `part2`, `part3` and `part4`.
Also when a user goes to a previous page and goes back the next page, the user should see what he/she entered before pressing the previous button.

Comment: you have a spa page or multiple page?

Comment: multiple pages containing forms

Comment: @Abdul Thanks I had the same problem, your question helped me in finding a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static solution for you is that you can set next previous button to every page and set the respective links on that pages

**for eg.**

**page1.html**

```
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="window.location='page4.html'">
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="window.location='page2.html'">
```

**page2.html**

```
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="window.location='page1.html'">
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="window.location='page3.html'">
```

**page3.html**

```
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="window.location='page2.html'">
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="window.location='page4.html'">
```

**page4.html**

```
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="window.location='page3.html'">
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="window.location='page1.html'">
```

Comment: this works but when i go to a previous a page and come back to the next page data inputted disappears

Comment: I have made some changes to the question can you please help me with that one too

Comment: Are you PHP into this ? then you can maintain this with session otherwise you have to set localStorage for this.

Comment: I used php for the sessions but how do I use it so it maintains the sessions from the previous page

Comment: You can refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791414/storing-form-data-as-a-session-variable) for maintain session variables on form

Comment: I have done that but when I use your solution. say if I am on page2 and I go back to page1 and then go back to page2 the form on page2 resets. how do I make it keep its values

Comment: You have to set `<?php echo $_SESSION["nameOnPage2"]; ?>` in your `input field value` then whenever you go back to that page session value will set again

Comment: I did dis but how do I set the session variables of page2 on page1

Answer (score 0):

You could create a button in html that links to a different page.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

Comment: and the data from the previous page where does it go?

Comment: I have created session variables for it on the next page. it is a multi page form so page1 has it's session variables on page2, page2 on page3 and so on