# Storing Form Data as a Session Variable PHP

Tags: php, forms, variables, session

I reviewed [Storing Form Data as a Session Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791414/storing-form-data-as-a-session-variable) but can't quite get it working for me and I have nearly the same code. Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
<?php
session_start();    
?>  

    <form action="checkout.php" method="post">
    <div>
        Customer ID: <input type="text" name="customer_id" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" />
    </form>
    ';

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['checkout'])) { 
       $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $_POST['customer_id'];
    } 
?>
```

The code above doesn't work, but the below does. I am typing the same number in the text box.

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['customer_id'] = 1024;
?>
```

Comment: variable names are case sensitive too ya know, and `$_session` is no exception

Comment: you should Uppercase the session $_SESSION because it is global

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, but it doesn't work in all caps either. I've tested it that way as well.

Comment: Try with `if(isset($_POST['customer_id'])) {`

Answer (score -1):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.superglobals.php
use `$_SESSION` not `$_session`
pay attention to the case, global variables are written in upper case.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, but it doesn't work in all caps either. I've tested it that way as well.